# CLI Message- trying to clone a repo

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a repo to my work computer so that I can work on a react tutorial and when I say git clone address of the repo I get the following message:

```
Cloning into 'ReduxSimpleStarter'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '145.40.335.302' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can someone please explain what these lines mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means you are using an ssh url, and your public key (in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) is not registered in the remote server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If this is a private server, check with its administrator in order for your key to be added.

You can test that with:

```
ssh -Tv <user>@my.server
```

Comment: Can you tell me a little more of how this work and how it is set up?

Comment: this is what I get when I enter the command you suggested: OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my.server: nodename nor servname provided, or not known. How can I check my server name?

Comment: @IvonneTerrero did you replace 'my.server' by your actual server? Is the server github.com?